# Best glues for attaching images to glass (Image facing the glass), and magnet questions

Tags: adhesives, glass, varnish, decoupage-glue

and thank you for any input you may be able to provide.

I was drawn to this site by the question and answer about beer bottle labels, but that doesn't seem to apply for what I have in mind, and neither do any other of the question/answer combos.

I am seeking to make refrigerator magnets with glass square fronts and disc magnet backs, and at this point am thinking in terms of two or three types of images to apply.

One might be color (pigment) inkjet printed images on cotton photo paper with full coverage, a second might be either cotton photo paper or some sort of printmaking paper like Canson Edition or Rives BFK block or line printing that would only have partial coverage with the image (although the photo paper would have some sort of coating), and the third might be cotton based paper suitable for oil painting with full coverage.

The oil paints I would use would be fast drying. Do you think some sort of varnish be necessary over the oil paint in order to get the best bond?

What would be the best type of glue to attach disk magnets? I’ve heard hot glue would be good, and I’ve also known people who would put their faith in E-6000

I don’t know if Mod podge would be sufficient for what I'm thinking of, and/or if it would work as a protective coating on the back of the image, and whether the back coating should be applied before or after the magnet?

Also, any recommendations of types and sources of disc magnets would be welcome, as well as advice about what magnets to avoid.

Thank you again.

KnowledgeSeeker

Comment: Hi KowledgeSeeker, you have written a clear and complete question. However, could you break it up into several questions? This way, the questions might be able to help out more people by being more general and easily findable. Since the question on varnish is concerned with the adhesive bond, they can be combined, but the question on sources and types of disc magnets should be a separate question (note also that we don't allow questions on where to *buy* magnets, if that was the intention). Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: Also, if you break your question up it will be easier to search and find that a few of your issues are already answered here.